# NetLogo (social network): How do you connect nodes based on probability?

Tags: netlogo, probability

I am trying to model an "online forum" where the model starts with 2 connected agents that are of 2 breeds (A-agents and B-agents).

1. With each iteration, an agent of one of the 2 breeds is created. Which breed of node is created; A-agent vs. B-agent is determined by a probability (see code).
2. The newly created agent (1 x A-agents or B-agents) then connects to either one of A-agents or B-agents based on a probability.

How do I make the newly created agent attach to one of the 2 breeds of agents based on probability of selection?

- If newly created node is A-agents = 58% chance of connecting to one of A-agents and 42% to one of B-agents?
- If newly created node is B-agents = 56% probability of connecting to an A-agent and 44% probability of connecting to B-agents

Here is my code so far, up to point 1.

```
breed [A-agents A-agent]
breed [B-agents B-agent]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  create-A-agents 1
  [ set shape "triangle"
    set size 1
    set color blue
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  create-B-agents 1 
  [ set shape "circle"
    set size 1
    set color red
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  ask B-agents [create-links-with A-agents [set color green]]
  tick
end

to go ;; create a new node based on the emprical user distribution of A-agents/B-agents
  let p random-float 100 ;; create a random number between 1-100
  if (p >= 97) [create-A-agents 1 
      [ set shape "triangle"        
        set size 1
        set color blue
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor]]
  if (p < 97) [create-B-agents 1
      [ set shape "circle"
        set size 1
        set color red
        setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]] 
  tick
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need something like this (for A-agents, you can write a similar for B-agents) - not tested and probably has syntax errors.

```
let test-num random-float 1
ifelse test-num < 0.58
[ create-link-with one-of other A-agents ]
[ create-link-with one-of B-agents ]
```

I haven't included any testing for whether there are actually any agents to connect to, but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I integrated your suggestion into the if statement from point 1 (under the agent attributes) and it worked.